# SQL Dump exclude old entries of table

Tags: mysql

I have searched the docs and don't know yet if what I ask is really possible, so I'd like to get some info about it:

I have a daily script that dumps the data of a production server database (MariaDB 5.5.35) to a development server. This dump is very long because the production server stores old data that are not needed for the development server, which only needs the recent entries. I'll give you an example just below :

```
id_log | product_id | price  | logged_at
1      | 15111      | 45.000 |  2017-01-01
2      | 15111      | 41.000 |  2020-01-01
```

I would like to dump only the entries of this table that have been logged in the current year, to limit the size of the dump. I haven't found anything like this in the docs.

I have already looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593148/mysql-dump-exclude-some-table-data/29494950) but it seems that the solution only proposes excluding **all** data of some tables, while I need to keep recent entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use where condition.

```
mysqldump <database name> <table name> \
  --where="timestamp >= '2019-01-01 00:00:00'" > dump.sql
```

[Documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqldump/)